# Is this function ok to convert binary to integer in c

Tags: c, data-conversion

I'm using this function to convert an 8-bit binary number represented as a boolean array to an integer. Is it efficient? I'm using it in an embedded system. It performs ok but I'm interested in some opinions or suggestions for improvement (or replacement) if there are any.

```
uint8_t b2i( bool *bs ){

            uint8_t ret = 0;

            ret  = bs[7] ?   1 : 0;
            ret += bs[6] ?   2 : 0;
            ret += bs[5] ?   4 : 0;
            ret += bs[4] ?   8 : 0;
            ret += bs[3] ?  16 : 0;
            ret += bs[2] ?  32 : 0;
            ret += bs[1] ?  64 : 0;
            ret += bs[0] ? 128 : 0;

            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: If the code is *working* then this would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you identified it as a bottleneck? Until then, don't bother.

Comment: My gut feeling says that if you have performance issues because of this, the real problem lies in the choice of data structures.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the array passed actually has less than 8 elements?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to say without a specific system in mind. Disassemble the code and see what you got. Benchmark your code on a specific system. This is the key to understanding manual optimization.

Generally, there are lots of considerations. The CPU's data word size, instruction set, compiler optimizer performance, branch prediction (if any), data cache (if any) etc etc.

To make the code perform optimally regardless of data word size, you can change `uint8_t` to `uint_fast8_t`. That is unless you need exactly 8 bits, then leave it as `uint8_t`.

Cache use may or may not be more efficient if given an up-counting loop. At any rate, loop unrolling is an old kind of manual optimization that we shouldn't use in modern programming - the compiler is more capable of making that call than the programmer.

The worst problem with the code is the numerous branches. These might cause a bottleneck.

Your code results in the following x86 machine code `gcc -O2`:

```
b2i:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+6], 0
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi+7]
        je      .L2
        add     eax, 2
.L2:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+5], 0
        je      .L3
        add     eax, 4
.L3:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+4], 0
        je      .L4
        add     eax, 8
.L4:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+3], 0
        je      .L5
        add     eax, 16
.L5:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+2], 0
        je      .L6
        add     eax, 32
.L6:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+1], 0
        je      .L7
        add     eax, 64
.L7:
        lea     edx, [rax-128]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
        cmovne  eax, edx
        ret
```

Whole lot of potentially inefficient branching. We can make the code both faster and more readable by using a loop:

```
uint8_t b2i (const bool bs[8])
{
  uint8_t result = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    result |= bs[8-1-i] << i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

(ideally the bool array should be arranged from LSB first but that would change the meaning of the code compared to the original)

Which gives this machine code instead:

```
b2i:
        lea     rsi, [rdi-8]
        mov     rax, rdi
        xor     r8d, r8d
.L2:
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rax+7]
        mov     ecx, edi
        sub     ecx, eax
        sub     rax, 1
        sal     edx, cl
        or      r8d, edx
        cmp     rax, rsi
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, r8d
        ret
```

More instructions but less branching. It will likely perform better than your code on x86 and other high end CPUs with branch prediction and instruction cache. But worse than your code on a 8 bit microcontroller where only the total number of instructions count.

Comment: @FridaKahlo I've never used any of that old hobbyist stuff, but the Godbolt site supports a gcc AVR port: https://godbolt.org/z/Qp9ZFA. Not obvious which code's the better there. Curiously though, the compiler added some "zero_reg" when optimizing my code, which I suppose is a zero-page RAM allocated variable(?). That was yet another performance aspect of many 8 bitters, they performed better with their pure 8 bit instruction set in the zero page.

Comment: @FridaKahlo If you want my opinion, then it is: all 8 bitters are obsolete crap and we ran out of reasons for using them 10 years ago. This coming from someone who's been programming plenty of them professionally over the past 15 years. You can get a 100 times more powerful MCU for the same price, such as Atmel SAM (Cortex M). It is better in every single way - including ease of use. 8-bitters are actually quite hard to program in C, they were all designed with assembler in mind.

Comment: @FridaKahlo I'm saying there's no reason to use AVR when you have SAM (or some other Cortex M family).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with a loop and bit shifts to reduce code repetition:

```
int b2i(bool *bs) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ret = ret << 1;
        ret += bs[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it "unrolling the loop" faster?

Comment: @FridaKahlo that's possible. A modern compiler would do that optimization itself. I don't know how it is on the compiler available to you in the embedded environment, but the best way to find out would be to test it.